# Sails.js 0.10 generators

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js

The upcoming Sails.js 0.10 features custom generators. (at the time of writing it is currently @ rc4)

There's a [migration page](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/Migration-Guide.md) on Sails github describing how wonderful generators are, but not so much how to go about installing them into your own application.

A few really interesting custom generators start to pop up:

1. [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth)
2. [sails-generate-gulp-bower](https://github.com/PaulAvery/sails-generate-gulp-bower)

The first one is available on npm. So it was a matter of `npm install` and generator was available in my app right away.

I wanted to try out the second one to replace **Grunt** with **Gulp**, but I couldn't install the generator.

Can anyone explain how to install custom generator and hook it up with Sails.js app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a sails-generator just like any other npm package:

```
npm install sails-generate-auth
```

The problem with [sails-generate-gulp-bower](https://github.com/PaulAvery/sails-generate-gulp-bower) is that it hasn't been released to npm yet.
You can trick npm by using the following url to install the latest version of it anyway.

```
npm install https://github.com/PaulAvery/sails-generate-gulp-bower/archive/master.tar.gz --save
```

But keep in mind that the author probably has his reason why he didn't release it.

Answer (score 0):

I created generaters to use gulp  with sails. https://github.com/Karnith/sails-generate-new-gulp

There are 4 in total that need to be used together with a .sailsrc file. They should be installed globally and then sails new can be used to create the app. Sails lift works also.

Comment: Thanks Karnith, I'll check it out!

Comment: The google group discussion is located here for future reference. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/WoR1qcQSm-8